# Handle division is undefined on JasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have variables in JasperReport 6.60 which is doing some weighted average, and I tried to avoid division by zero by passing it through IF condition but it still producing "Division is undefined"

Let's say I want to show a variable $V{weighted_avg} on a group called ([Group] round), which is consist of two rounds. On the 1st round, $V{divisor} is zero (0), but on the 2nd round $V{divisor} is not zero

The variable $V{weighted_avg} contains expression :

```
IF($V{divisor}.compareTo(BigDecimal(0.00)) == 1, $V{dividend}.divide($V{divisor}, new MathContext(4)), null)
```

it will produced error "Division is undefined" on that expression when calculated.

But if I am doing this :

```
IF($V{divisor}.compareTo(BigDecimal(0.00)) == 1, "> 0", "< 0")
```

the result is correctly showed.

All variables is Bigdecimal and I expected the $V{weighted_avg} is showing "null" when the $V{divisor} is zero

Comment: I got a "temporary" solution, I set the $V{divisor} value to null on the detail band, so they did not produce error on [Group] band

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin `IF` function evaluates all its arguments, you need to use the Java ternary operator so that only the expression that corresponds to the matching branch gets evaluated.

As in

```
$V{divisor}.compareTo(BigDecimal(0.00)) == 1 ? $V{dividend}.divide($V{divisor}, new MathContext(4)) : null
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it works perfectly with your answer. I was not thinking about ternary operator.